# How to change value of mat-button-toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material

I come to you because I'm stuck.

I'm trying to change the value of the toggle button when I click on another item.

```
  <mat-button-toggle-group
    #myButton
    style="float: right;"
    name="toggleDimensionTime"
    (change)="onChangeTime($event.value)"
    value="year"
    aria-label="twcenmt mat-h2"
  >
    <mat-button-toggle value="year">Année</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="month">Mois</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

I created a reference variable to have it at the start of a function.

```
  @ViewChild('myButton', { static: false }) myButton: ElementRef;
```

I don't see which element changed when I console.log my button.

Thank You

Comment: Can you also share your functions in ts: onChange(event), onChangeTime(event) and also where are you doing console.log?

Comment: I do an onClick on another element and I do the console.log in the onClick.

Comment: @zwei try this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-toggle-group?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoggle.component.ts